Android Studio gets stuck in "Terminating the app" every time I want to run a program in emulator... beginning of: kernel, system, crash, main
sorry but this is probably going to be a long one. Its my first time building an App with Android Studio and pretty much with Java. I'm trying to build a Chronometer.  It was doing good and running properly but yesterday out of the blue it stopped working. Tried debugging it on several ways and cant go past it. Even more, I tried running other previous "simplier" programs that used to work fine and get the same error. It seems that it just cant start an app.
Its always the same routine, the bottom bar goes from "Building the Gradle" to "Terminating the app" and it will get STUCK on that process. Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed?
At first I thought it was the Chronometer program because of its length and variables involved, but now that Ive been trying it to isolate the source I have been moving back and forth previous attempts of the program that used to work and its doing exactly  the same. and the issue keeps saying on the logcat it shows:
--------beginning of kernel
--------beginning of system
--------beginning of crash
--------beginning of main
I deployed all the info from the logcat trying to find what went wrong but Im getting lost in all the logs.
At one point, reading on possible fixtures somebody posted that they recommend me to terminating the abd, and now a section of my code I cant call back. Mainly, do you know of any issues with the running of an app that could cause it?
I got the idea from
https://youtu.be/Dr-VtCbev10?si=6NIXDvrXr5Fqqp8f    Kudos to them.
Heres what I have for that program so far and it doesnt want to run:
`**Acticity Main activity_main.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation='vertical'
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TimerValue"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="0.00.000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnstart"
            android:text="Start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnpause"
            android:text="Pause"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnlap"
            android:text="Lap"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Cycl"
            android:text="Number of Cycles"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MIN"
            android:text="Total Minutes"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SEC"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Total Seconds"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MILLIS"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Total Millis"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Cycles"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextTotalMin"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextTotalSec"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextTotalMilli"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>




**ROW XML row.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text" />
</LinearLayout>


**MAIN ACTIVITY MainActivity.java**


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button btnStart,btnPause,btnLap; //Declaration of variables to be associated to Objects
    TextView txtTimer;
    TextView TextTotalMin;
    TextView TextTotalSec;
    TextView TextTotalMill;
    TextView TotalCycles;
    Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    LinearLayout container;
    long startTime=0L, TimeinMilliseconds=0L,timeSwapBuff=0L,updateTime=0L; //Variables to display time
    public ArrayList<Double> cycles=new  ArrayList<>();
    int mins,secs,milliseconds,totalmins=0,totalsecs=0,totalmillis=0,carrymins=0,carrysecs=0;


    Runnable updateTimerTread=new Runnable() { //Time registering function!!!!!!
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimeinMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-startTime;
            updateTime = timeSwapBuff+TimeinMilliseconds;
            //int secs=(int)(updateTime/1000);
            secs=(int) (updateTime/1000);
            //int mins=secs/60;
            mins=secs/60;
            secs%=60;
            //int milliseconds=(int)(updateTime%1000);
            milliseconds=(int)(updateTime%1000);
            txtTimer.setText(""+mins+"."+String.format("%2d",secs)+"."+String.format("%3d",milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this,0);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        btnStart=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstart); //Address linked to physical Object (Variable BtnStart to Button that says start)
        btnPause=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnpause);
        btnLap=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlap);
        txtTimer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimerValue);

        TextTotalMin=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextTotalMin);
        TextTotalSec=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextTotalSec);
        TextTotalMill=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextTotalMilli);
        TotalCycles=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Cycles);

        container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    //Declaration of Method, what do we want the variable to do when Object gets clicked
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startTime= SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerTread,0);
            }
        });

        btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timeSwapBuff+=TimeinMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerTread);
                LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
                TextView txtValue=(TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
                txtValue.setText((txtTimer.getText()));
                cycles.addAll(Arrays.asList((Double.valueOf(mins)),(Double.valueOf(secs)),(Double.valueOf(milliseconds))));
                System.out.println(cycles);
                //System.out.println(cycles.size());
                for (int i =0;i<cycles.size();i+=3){
                    totalmins +=cycles.get(i);
                    //System.out.println(totalmins);
                }
                for (int i =1;i<cycles.size();i+=3){
                    totalsecs +=cycles.get(i);
                    //System.out.println(totalsecs);
                }
                for (int i =2;i<cycles.size();i+=3){
                    totalmillis +=cycles.get(i);
                    //System.out.println(totalmillis);
                }

                //NEW CRASHING REASON
                if (totalmillis/1000>=1){
                    carrysecs=totalmillis/1000;
                    totalmillis=totalmillis%1000;
                }
                if ((totalsecs)/60>=1){
                    carrymins=(totalsecs)/60;
                    totalsecs=(totalsecs)%60;
                }

                TextTotalMin.setText(String.valueOf(totalmins+carrymins));
                TextTotalSec.setText(String.valueOf(totalsecs+carrysecs));
                TextTotalMill.setText(String.valueOf(totalmillis));
                TotalCycles.setText(String.valueOf((cycles.size()/3)));
                //

                System.out.println(totalmins);
                System.out.println(totalsecs);
                System.out.println(totalmillis);
                totalmins=0; totalsecs=0; totalmillis=0; carrymins=0; carrysecs=0;
                container.addView(addView);


            }
        });

        btnLap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
                TextView txtValue=(TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
                txtValue.setText((txtTimer.getText()));
                container.addView(addView);
            }
        });

    }
}`


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Solution wasn't in the code, for some reason updating my Android Studio Version solved it
